# Adding/removing user role on his login - based on non-Drupal tables

Tags: drupal, authentication, drupal-7

I have recently transferred [a Flash/Perl card game](http://preferans.de) from using phpBB 3 as backend to Drupal 7 and it has worked well, but I'm hesitant to (re)enable the forum - because some users at my old site had been freaking me out.

I would like to offer a forum at my site again, but only to the users, who are playing long enough at my site and have a good enough reputation. Both informations (how many games played + reputation) are maintained by my Perl-game and are kept in non-Drupal tables (but in the same database as the Drupal tables). And I have created a Drupal user role of *trusted user*:

```
# select * from drupal_role;
 rid |        name        | weight
-----+--------------------+--------
   1 | anonymous user     |      0
   2 | authenticated user |      1
   3 | trusted user       |      2
(3 rows)
```

I could modify 2 spots in my game - where the games are counted and where reputation is being changed - and then call 'insert/delete from users_roles where uid=?', but maybe there is a better spot in Drupal, where I could **change a user role on his login**?

I.e. a user (re)visits my site, his *reputation* and *number of games* are checked by 2 quick select queries against my non-Drupal tables and then he's added (or removed - if his reputation has decreased) to the *trusted user* role and can write in forum.

Thank you!
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the amount of users, it might be a better idea performance-wise to actually give them the necessary roles when they do something instead of executing two queries on every single page load.

If you want to do it, you can use [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) to add roles to the global $user object.

Answer (score 0):

User [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) for controlling points and changing user roles. Also enable PHP Filter module for executing custom PHP code in Rules for running custom queries.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [hook_user_login](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7)? You would need to put it in custom module, but you should then be able to add the role to the user after he logs in via that hook.

Comment: Hello jdwfly, I've tried hook_user_login but it seems to be called only when the user really submits his password. I was hoping there is some other hook available, for cases when a user re-visits the Drupal 7 site, but doesn't have to enter the password, because the cookies are still valid...

Comment: Thats true, the hook only fires when they actually log in. You could use rules like Nikit suggested and fire a rule when a page is viewed and then you could fire your custom php then. This would obviously run on every page view so you would want to make sure you optimize it so that you aren't doing queries when you don't need to.

Comment: You could use any hook that is invoked early like hook_init() and then change global $user.